# How to populate an android spinner with a java String array

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am new to Android and working on a "project" as a teaching method.

I added a spinner on the UI

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:layout_marginBottom="38dp" />
```

and i am trying to pass on the values from a String Array

```
String[] branchesArray = st.split(";");
```

I have been looking around the web for this one, but i just cant make it to work.

The most popular seems to be something like that

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter0 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, branchesArray);
```

which is giving me this error

> The constructor ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.getData, int, String[]) is undefined

and, according to an other post using this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter0 = new ArrayAdapter<String>
         (Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, branchesArray);
```

gives me this error

> No enclosing instance of the type Activity is accessible in scope

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your activity class?

Comment: Why have you written Activity.class? Give your activity class name here.

Comment: hmmm....i will sound stupid, definitely. What is the activity class. the java or the xml?

Comment: It is the class name in java that extends Activity or ActionBarActivity.

Comment: If i got it right its the java class i am working on. then this is MainActivity

`public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity is a class. If you want to reference your current class just use `this` or perhaps `MainActivity.this`.

Comment: That was it. feel quite stupid now. But this thing is so much harder than any java programming. difficult to get my head around to it.
Thanks again

Comment: @SkarosIlias don't worry you'll get used to it. It's called Object Oriented Programming so you might want to read about it :)